# Unity error - "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Action("

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to add function to an action, they don't have parametrs. I don't understand why i can't add function.
First sctipt which creates and invokes action.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private int _health;

    private int _currentHealth;

    public event Action OnHitAction;

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        _currentHealth -= damage;

        if (_currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            //Die?.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            OnHitAction?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Second script adds function to action.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator _animator;
    private PlayerMover _playerMover;

    private void Start()
    {
        Player player = new();
        player.OnHitAction += Hit();// Error is here
        _playerMover = GetComponent<PlayerMover>();
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Hit()
    {
        _animator.SetTrigger("Hit");
    }
}
```

Comment: When assigning a delgate you need to assign the function not executed it and assign the result. More on Delegates and how to use them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hit()
```

already executes the method when this line is executed and tries to assign the "return value" - but it returns `void` so it can't be assigned / added to your `Action`

You want

```
player.OnHitAction += Hit;
```

which refers to the method but doesn't execute it